# Sending JSON request to uservoice

Tags: php, jsonp, uservoice

I am currently using a contact us form that send the user information to uservoice. I am using a jquery code that send a json request to uservoice.

Here's the code:

```
$('#test_form').submit(function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();  



    var uvSubdomain = "initech";/



    var uvKey = "5JVoVrAGdl4pMkcEkIeIDA";




    var message = $('#message').val();

    var subject = $('#subject').val();

    var name = $('#name').val();

    var email = $('#email').val();



    $.jsonp({

        url: 'https://' + uvSubdomain + '.uservoice.com/api/v1/tickets/create_via_jsonp.json\\?callback=?',

        data: {

            client: uvKey,
            ticket: {
                message: message,
                subject: subject
            },
            name: name,
            email: email
        },

        success: function(data) {

            alert('Successfully submitted ticket!');  // You might want to redirect the user here, or show a stylized message to them.

        },

        error: function(d, msg) {

            alert("Error"); 

        }

    });

    return false;
});
```

Now I want send the json request with the help of PHP.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion or code for this.

Thanks you

Comment: _Now I want send the json request with the help of PHP._ you mean you want the response as json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl extension:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test.com');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name1=value1&name2=value2'); //post data
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

if you connect to https site you must add one of this:

```
//easy solution
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//secure solution
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CAINFO,"/path_to_certificate/cert.crt");
```

Comment: Alternative to This Approach ?? without curl extension how can we use it ??